# How to print code embedded in a here-doc to lexical filehandle

Tags: perl, file-io, heredoc

I'm trying to create a script that will generate perl code from a template, and I'm having trouble understanding the error being thrown and why my workaround fixes it.

This example is contrived, but it demonstrates the issue:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $name = shift; # from @ARGV
my $file = sprintf "%s.pm", $name;

open my $fh, ">", $file
  or die "error: open(>, '$file'): $!";

print $fh << "MODULE";
package $name;

#
# blah blah
#

use strict;
use warnings;

require Exporter;

our \@ISA       = qw| Exporter |;
our \@EXPORT    = qw| |; # automatic exports
our \@EXPORT_OK = qw| |; # on-demand exports

# CODE

1;
MODULE

close $fh;
```

When running this script, I get the following error:

```
$ perl script.pl Foo
Invalid version format (non-numeric data) at script.pl line 11, near "package "
syntax error at script.pl line 11, near "package $name"
BEGIN not safe after errors--compilation aborted at script.pl line 17.
```

Originally this script was just printing to stdout instead of writing to file -- no errors thrown. After adding the file handling and receiving this error, I then tried to just use a bare filehandle -- again no errors thrown.

So if I merely replace "$fh" with "FH" everywhere, the script works as expected. What is it about the lexical filehandle causing this to choke?

Comment: Try using IO::Handle and the $fh->print() syntax.

Comment: @AKHolland: Conveniently, `IO::File` (and so `IO::Handle`) is loaded on demand by any Perl v5.14 or later. That means you can just use any file handle as if it's an `IO::File` object without adding an explicit `use IO::File` beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl is an ambiguous language. It means that it's not always clear how it should be parsed. In some situations, `perl` has to guess how to parse something. There's a grammatical ambiguity in

```
print $fh << "MODULE";
```

Specifically, the `<<` can be a left shift operator or the start of here-doc.

---

There are two paths you can follow to address the issue.

- You can remove the ambiguity:

  ```
  print $fh +<< "MODULE";
  ```

  ```
  print $fh (<< "MODULE");
  ```

  ```
  print { $fh } << "MODULE";
  ```

  ```
  $fh->print(<< "MODULE");
  ```
- You can trick `perl` into guessing correctly:

  ```
  print $fh <<"MODULE";
  ```

---

Note that `print $fh +<< "MODULE";` introduces an alternate ambiguity. Is `+` a binary or unary `+` operator? Thankfully, it's interpreted as a unary-`+` as desired.

---

By the way, `<<"MODULE"` can be shortened to `<<MODULE`.

Comment: it seems strange to me that the ambiguity is resolved by assuming a left-shift operation _when one of the operands is a literal, non-numeric string_. even the `use warnings` pragma knows `"MODULE"` is an invalid argument to `<<` (although the pragma checks are prob way too late to be resolving semantics)

Answer (score 2):

There should be no space after `<<` marking the here document, so

```
print $fh << "MODULE";
```

should be

```
print $fh <<"MODULE";
```

or more neatly

```
print $fh <<MODULE;
```

or perhaps

```
print $fh (<< "MODULE");
```

As it is the `<<` is being treated as a left-shift operator and Perl continues to try to compile the `package` statement. Finding no valid package name it tries to use `$name`as a version number, and complains because it isn't one

Comment: `perldoc perlop` : "There may not be a space between the << and the identifier, unless the identifier is explicitly quoted."  The OP uses explicit quotes.

Comment: @toolic: I guess that's just wrong. I'll submit a bug report

Comment: also remember in the bug report that this behavior only occurs when using lexical filehandles, it's more specific than just the spacing around the `<<` operator. and thanks for the insight!

Comment: @ardnew: It's more general than that. A here document can be used anywhere a string may appear in a program, and so it may be preceded by many things other than a `print` call. Without a space after the `<<` it will be treated as a left-shift if it makes syntactic sense.

Comment: @ardnew, There's no bug. Generally speaking, `<< "EOF"` works perfectly fine. The actual problem is that you encountered a grammatical ambiguity. Claims that there shouldn't be a after the `<<` marking the here-document are false (if what follows is quoted).